# How can we save the rails form as a pdf and download it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation

I have an invoice model with fields: name, designation, start_time, end_time, etc.
My requirement is to store these values in the database as a PDF and provide a way to download the PDF. Is there any way to store it, and if so, how?

Comment: Do you want to store a PDF in the database, or store the values in a database and then provide the ability to download the record as a PDF?

Comment: If you really want to save the PDF in the database, it would be better to save it as a file in the hard drive and store its path in the database.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to store values as fields in the database, whenever user click download you can fetch the values from the database and stored in the pdf for downloading. 
Second method is you store the file in your server or computer and store path of it in the database.